# Limit of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}-1}{x^2+y^2-4y+4}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would like to find the limit of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}-1}{x^2+y^2-4y+4}$ as $(x,y)\to(0,2)$. WolframAlpha says it is $1/2$ but how do I get there? Tried multiplying with the conjugate square root and writing the expression in polar coordinates but couldn't get the answer right.

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is $$\frac12$$....Try multiplying numerator and denominator by $${\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}+1}$$

which gives 
$$\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}-1)({\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}+1})}{(x^2+y^2-4y+4)({\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}+1})}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2 $$$$=\frac{x^2+y^2-4y+5-1}{(x^2+y^2-4y+4)({\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}+1})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}+1}$$

Now $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,2)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4y+5}+1} \to \frac{1}{1+1} \to \frac 12$$

Comment: That's what I did but keep getting $0$ in the denominator :(